# Convert Script to CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Please, can you help me with this query?

```
SELECT 
    [festno], 2 
FROM 
    dbo.V_sadad_isar 
WHERE 
    [festno] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [festno]
                 FROM 
                     (SELECT
                          [festno], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [festno] ORDER BY fisar DESC) AS rn
                      FROM
                          dbo.V_sadad_isar) T
                 GROUP BY festno
                 HAVING MAX(rn) = 1)  
    AND [darsad_janbaz] <> 50
```

Comment: Please help me to get this script in shape cte

Comment: Is that comment the same as the question? Why are you posting it again there?

Comment: You need to explain what's wrong with the query.

Comment: There's no CTE or script in the question.

Comment: What should I do to improve the readability of this query?

Comment: I really want to convert this query to CTE

Comment: Put `WITH` before it and `AS CTE_name` after it, and put it at the beginning of another query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT [festno], 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [festno] ORDER BY fisar DESC) AS rn
    FROM dbo.V_sadad_isar
), cte2 as (
    SELECT DISTINCT [festno]
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY festno
    HAVING MAX(rn) = 1
)

SELECT fastno, 2
FROM dbo.V_sadad_isar
WHERE festno IN (SELECT festno FROM cte2)
```

But it can be simplified to this:

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT DISTINCT [festno]
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY festno
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)

SELECT fastno, 2
FROM dbo.V_sadad_isar
WHERE festno IN (SELECT festno FROM cte)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @MohammadBayat If it helped, you should accept the answer and (optionally) upvote it :)